# DSE Shark worker Jetty port

Tags: datastax-enterprise

I just read that [the random Shark worker Jetty port can't be fixated](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/spark-standalone.html#configuring-ports-for-network-security). The previous link states:

> Jetty-based. Each of these services starts on a random port that
>   cannot be configured

However, reading [the DSE documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/sec/secConfFirePort.html) I see no note on this. Is the DSE documentation wrong or has the Datastax somehow managed to patch Jetty to use a fixed port?

Answer (score 0):

This is correct, you can configure the worker port using the SPARK_WORKER_PORT environment variable.

Check out Al's post to see how you would do it if you were building the integration yourself:
http://tobert.github.io/post/2014-07-15-installing-cassandra-spark-stack.html

#### Of course DSE does this for you automatically under the covers : )

Comment: But my quote is not for SPARK_WORKER_PORT, but rather the worker Jetty server that serves "File server for file and jars", "Http Broadcast" and "Class file server (Spark Shell only)". Which port is it equivalent to in http://www.datastax.com/documentation/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/sec/secConfFirePort.html ?